# \rowcolor overwrites vertical table border

Tags: tables, color

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hhline}

%--------------------------------------------------------%
%   BEGIN DOCUMENT
%--------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Fruits!}\tabularnewline
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Fruits}}                                                                                 \\ \hline
     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Billy}                          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Jean}                     \\ \hline
Rank & Item                                             & Weight & Item                                      & Weight \\ \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.9} 1    & Apples.         & 0.331  & Oranges.  & 0.423  \\
2    & Bananas.        & 0.170  & Strawberries. & 0.423  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%--------------------------------------------------------%
%   END DOCUMENT
%--------------------------------------------------------%

\end{document}
```

I'm using \rowcolor to color in certain rows of my table, but I notice that this causes some of the vertical borders to be covered. I've tried using the package `hhline` but it doesn't seem to help.

[image]

Comment: This is viewer-dependent. Here's [a view under Sumatra](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ecd1r.png) (no problem).

Comment: By Sumatra do you mean SumatraPDF? I've been using the web latex tool called Overleaf...what could be causing one viewer to show the border but the other doesn't?

Comment: ...the rendering algorithm, as well as the zoom resolution. When you zoom in to a high level in the resulting PDF, I'm guessing the output will show vertical rules everywhere, just like it does between `Item` and `Weight`. You can increase the rule width by adding `\usepackage{array} \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}`. We have a similar question about this somewhere else...